# Conditional statement after the Or operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators, conditional-statements

In JavaScript, is it possible to place a Conditional statement after an Or operator? If so, why is the following fails for me?

```
var value = 1 || true ? 2 : 3;    // equals to 2
```

When I set value to be equals to `[1 || true ? 2 : 3]`, I get an unexpected result. 
The result that get is that:

```
value == 2
```

I've expected value to be equals to 1 (`value= = 1`), since 1 is truthy, and the Or statement should have return 1. The conditional statement is not even supposed to be executed.

The only way val can be equals to 2 (`val == 2`) is if the Or operator is behaving not as expected, and runs the second part of the Or statement and the Conditional statement that is in it.

Why is it behaving that way?

Comment: Because it's interpreted as `(1 || true) ? 2 : 3`

Comment: Ohh.. I forgot about operator precedence ..

Answer (score 3):

> I've expected value to be equals to 1 (value = 1), since 1 is truthy

To get that, you need parens:

```
var value = 1 || (true ? 2 : 3);
// --------------^------------^
```

Without them, the `||` is between `1` and `true`, and then the conditional operator's first operand is the result of that (which is `1`).

This is because `||` has higher precedence than the conditional operator (just); [here's a table on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Answer (score 0):

Because [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR) has precedence over the [Conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator. Then your statement is actually interpreted as:

```
(1 || true) ? 2 : 3;
```

Which obviously evaluates to `2`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: Thank you guys for the fast response (: